# How to open ssh session using tcl expect and redirecting output to local machine

Tags: tcl, expect

I am new to TCL expect, i want to connect one ssh session, on the remote machine i want to execute `"radiusd -X"` this command will through log message on console normally. I want to capture those logs and need to store on local machine(where i initiated the ssh session)

Someone pls help me out for the TCL expect coding part by explaining

Comment: Why do you think you need `expect`? If you need to automate sending the password, you are encouraged to set up ssh keys instead. Then you can simply do `set output [exec ssh user@host radiusd -X]`

Comment: radiusd -X is not password "radiusd -X" is a linux command to enable radius server log on debug mode, once after the command on the console throw the error and log messages, i want to capture those error and log messages and need to send to local machine(where i intiated the ssh session)

Comment: all of which my example does. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do happens automatically.

If you ssh into a remote host and execute a command there, the output is shown in your local terminal.

It can be captured even with a shell redirect.

Example:

```
str@suse131-intel:~> ssh holiday-house-hamburg.com ls -l /
insgesamt 76
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root  5920 17. Mär 09:28 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root   152 17. Mär 09:28 boot
drwxr-xr-x  8 root    root   800 16. Jun 21:01 dev
```

If you want to capture the output with Tcl do as glenn jackman told you.